# how to populate html select element options in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I need to populate html select options with all states in USA. It would be helpful if I can see an example. Do I need to have all the states defined in a scope variable?

Thanks!

Comment: would be no different than any other example you can find anywhere ... *including the angular documentation* ... of arrays populating `ng-options` for a select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all, No need to define all states individually in scope. you can make simple use of $watch service in angular js.

[please refer the jsfiddle link here:](http://jsfiddle.net/A24tR/2/)

states and cities can be taken inside an array of objects and data-ng-options is used to show the options which will be loaded from controller. $watch will watch on change of state and load the city accordingly.

```js
function Controller($scope) {

    var states = [{
         "Name": "karnataka",
            "cities": [{
          
                "Name": "bangalore"
        }, {
         
                "Name": "mangalore"
        }, {
           
                "Name": "mysore"
        }]
    }, {
     
            "Name": "maharashtra",
            "cities": [{
           
                "Name": "Mumbai"
        }, {
           
                "Name": "pune"
        }, {
          
                "Name": "nagpur"
        }]
    }];

    $scope.groups = states;
    $scope.currentGroup = states[0];
    $scope.currentItems = $scope.currentGroup.cities;
    $scope.currentItem = $scope.currentItems[0];
    
    $scope.$watch('currentGroup', function () {
          $scope.currentItems = $scope.currentGroup.cities;
          $scope.currentItem = $scope.currentGroup.cities[0];
      }); 
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<section ng-app ng-controller="Controller">
 
    
        <div class="span4">
            <label for="cboGroup">States</label>
    <select data-ng-model="currentGroup" data-ng-options="group.Name for group in groups"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <label for="cboItem">Cities</label>
    <select data-ng-model="currentItem" data-ng-options="item.Name for item in currentItems"></select>
        </div>
   <div>
       Selected city :  {{currentItem.Name}}
   <div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

yes the best way would be store it in an array of objects as a scope variable and then use it in your template.

Something like this....

let's say $scope.allState[] is an array of objects of all states in USA.

then in your templates try it as....

```
<select type="text" name="name" id="name"  
                    data-ng-model="formData.state"
                  ng-options="state for state in allState"
                    required >
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                    </select>
```